# Standard way to Encrypt Data using Public key in Java

Tags: java, encryption

My application has to publish a file to several clients over a common channel. I have been doing below process to encrypt it

1. Generating a symmetric key to encrypt the data.
2. then encrypting this key with RSA public key and publish it.

Considering all the clients of this application have application's RSA public key, is there any standard format to encrypt a file before publishing it?

Comment: Your description is strange. #2 means that every client which is on the "common" channel has the same private key. This is usually not done. But then you say that everyone has the *application's RSA public key*. Can you elaborate on your system? Also, are you really just asking about message encoding?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for taking an interest in the crypto questions on SO, your contributions are very much valued (by me anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there are several standard formats for encryption. One of the most popular standard format is [Cryptographic Message Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) (CMS). Also refer to specs for CMS at [Internet Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652It). This format is widely used for for `S/MIME` mail message security.

[Bouncy Castle API](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/BC+Version+2+APIs#%20BCVersion2APIs-CMS)s provides a wonderful support for this. BC's `bcmail-jdkNN-MMM.jar` is the Bouncy Castle `SMIME/CMS` library which is of your use. It is a package for processing `RFC 3852` Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) objects - also referred to as `PKCS#7` (formerly `RFC 2630, 3369`), and also dealing with `S/MIME` objects (`RFC 3851`).

Another popular standard format, [XML Encryption format](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-encrypt/). end-to-end security for applications that require secure exchange of structured data. `XML` itself is the most popular technology for structuring data, and therefore XML-based encryption is the natural way to handle complex requirements for security in data interchange applications.

Comment: Only one more? What about PGP for instance? Using XML for encryption is pretty dangerous unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: That's true with XML. Anyways I have changed wordings to introduce XML encryption format. :)